# Discussion list filters

Tags: discussion-board

I have an issue with Discussion list topic filters. So when you open a new topic the post automatically shows "Oldest" -messages and I need to change it to show "Newest" by default.

I haven't been able to do/find a place where to do that.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint are you working with? I noticed that when I create a discussion board on SharePoint 2013 the default views are sort of customized for that app and probably should not be modified all that much. The Subject view has some preset filters that already do what you described above. There is a "Recent" view that sorts the conversations showing the newest one at the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: I use Sharepoint 2013. I have managed to get the comments to show on the descending order by using SP Designer but the filter names still remains the same "Oldest" etc. because the change haven't been made by using built in tools.Yes the filters can be clicked but my customer wants them "Newest" to open by default.

Comment: ooohhh I see what your talking about the comment sort filters. sorry about that, well at least they have the "Oldest and Newest" sort buttons at the top of the comments section for users to choose. I'm not sure if this default can be changed though.